# Call the Button contrustor from inside a class' __init__

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, tkinter

My GUI program uses a number of buttons that have a couple very specific features, so I'm writing a class that wraps these methods around a button so I don't need to keep rewriting simple functions for each button. I have the class:

```
class ToggleableButton(Button):     
    __isToggled = False
    __root = None
    __bindMap = []

    # how do I correctly structure the init ?
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        Button.__init__(self, master, cnf, kw)

    def bind(self, root, bindKey, func):
        # doing stuff

    def Toggle(self, toggle=False):
        # doing stuff
```

and I want to be able to create the object just like I'd create a button:

```
drawButton = ToggleableButton(frame, image=img, width=30, command=func)
drawButton = ToggleableButton(frame, image=anotherimg)
```

how can I declare the class `__init__` method to mimic that of the button? Currently if I write `test = ToggleableButton(frame, text="hi", width=10, command=func)` I'll get the error:

```
tools.py, line 59, in __init__
    Button.__init__(self, master, cnf, kw)
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply (splat) the extra keyword arguments:

```
Button.__init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)
                                   ^^
```

Otherwise, you will be passing the whole `kw` dict as a single positional argument.  This raises an error since `Button.__init__` only accepts three positional arguments (`self`, `master`, and `cnf`), not four.